# django codemirror get code from editor

Tags: python, django, codemirror

Below is my code for code editor in template

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'codemirror.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'codemirror.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'clike.js' %}"></script>

<script>

var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('text_area'), {
  value: "int main()",
  mode: "text/x-c++src",
  lineNumbers: true,
  indentUnit: 4,
});
</script>
```

Using div tag

```
<div id="text_area" name="text_area" style="margin-top: 0px;" ></div>
```

How do i get the code after submit button from post method?

Note:
I am using CodeMirror library from [github](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror)

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to get the code with

```
myCodeMirror.getValue()
```